# How to hide columns in HTML table if rows under this column is empty?

Tags: javascript, html, sql, asp.net-core, razor

I have a table with this columns in HTML page. Razor is used for output. The values are generated dynamically from the database.

| ID | Name | Week_1 | Week_2 | ... | Week_52 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1 | 3 |  | 1 |  |
| 2 | Test2 | 2 | 3 | 3 |  |
| 3 | Test3 | 5 |  | 1 |  |

And for example I want to hide column Week_52 because column has no values in all rows.
The column (table -> thead -> tr -> th) has no children, so I don't understand how they can be associated with values in (table -> tbody -> tr -> td).

How can I do this in vanilla javascript? Or maybe there is another solution?

Edited. 0 -> empty

Comment: Is there a totals row beneath each column by chance? If so, it could be read by JS to determine which columns are empty and a loop used to remove each corresponding data and header cell. Otherwise, a total will need to be generated first, although this would only require two passes.

Comment: I didn't really understand what the totals row means. The sum of each column? That is not. The table is the same as in the example, only larger. I just want to hide column with rows equal 0 like Week_52. Actually there are empty values. 0 stands for simplicity.

Comment: Did you put the 0 values there or was it rendered that way? You might need to show the source of the rendered table if anyone is to understand how it could be parsed to remove the column.

Comment: No, I didn't put a 0 value there, it's an empty string. It was my fail, I will edit table.

Comment: Razor can do that for you?

Comment: Can you share a simple demo with code?Maybe you can try to check if rows under this column is empty in @{} with c#code,and then show the columns which are not empty.

Comment: Yes, I can use Razor, but my experience with Razor quite low. How can check if rows under this column is empty in @{} with c#code?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I added id="myAnchor" to the table with attribute data-currentweek. (I get currentweek value from database using Razor)

```
function hideWeekColumns(){

        const myAnchor = document.getElementById("myAnchor"); 
        currentweek = myAnchor.dataset.currentweek-1;          
                
        let weeks = document.getElementsByClassName('column week');     
        let weeks_array = Array.from( weeks );      
        weeks_array.splice(0, currentweek); // from position 0, remove 1 element   

        weeks_array.forEach(element => {
          element.style.display = 'none';
        });       
};
hideWeekColumns();
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different take on the last answer with comments, still in jquery though.

hideemptycols()

```
   function hideemptycols() {
       var hide = {}  //set an object to track the qty of cells within each column that HAVE zero data
       //to hide a column including header, all cells within need to be empty
       $('table tbody tr').each(function () {  // iterate through all rows
           $(this).find('td').each(function (i, v) {  // with each of the rows cells
               if (!hide[i]) { hide[i] = 0 }  //check if the object contains the column index, if not add it and give it a zero value

               if ($.trim($(v).text()).length == 0) {  //check the length of data if zero
                   $(v).hide()// hide the cell
               }
               else {
                   hide[i] += 1//add 1 against the column for every cell found with data
               }
           })
       })
       $.each(hide,function (index, EmptyQty) {  //loop the object
           if (EmptyQty == 0) {  //with each column if the qty of cells with dataequals zero then hide the column
               $('table tr th:nth-child(' + index + ')').hide()//get the column by index and hide               
           }
       })
  
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

By Using jquery you can achieve this

The first step includes a jquery file and then

at bottom add

```
 <script>
    let hide = {}
    for(let i = 1; i <= 52; i++){
        hide[i] = true
    }

    $('table tbody tr').each(function(){
        let cn = -1
        $(this).find('td').each(function(){
            if($.trim($(this).text()) != '0' && hide[cn]){
                hide[cn] = false
            }
            cn++
        })
    })
    console.log(hide)
    for (var key of Object.keys(hide)) {
        if(hide[key]){
            $('table tr td:nth-child('+key+')').hide()
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I cannot use jquery. Is it possible to do it in pure javascript? And I have a lot of weeks, not only week_52.

Comment: Convert this code to javascript